# Difficult algorithm: Optimal Solution to 1

Tags: algorithm

This is one of those difficult algorithms just because there are so many options. Imagine a number 'N' and a set of Primes under 10 i.e. {2, 3, 5, 7}. The goal is to  keep dividing N till we reach 1. If at any steps N is not divisible by any of the given primes then you can an operation out of:

i) N= N-1
OR ii) N=N+1

This will ensure that N is even and we can continue.

The goal should be achieved while using minimum number of operations.

Please note that this may sound trivial i.e. you can implement a step in your algo that "if N is divisible by any prime then divide it". But this does not always produce the optimal solution

E.g. if N=134: Now 134 is divisble by 2. if you divide by 2 , you get 67. 67 is not divisible by any prime, so you do an operation and N will be 66/68 both of which require another operation. So total 2 operations.

Alternatively, if N=134 and you do an operation N=N+1 i.e. N=135, In this case the total operations needed to reach 1 is 1. So this is the optimal solution

Comment: What is the question exactly? "How can it be done?" What did you try?

Comment: `if N=134 and you do an operation N=N+1 i.e. N=135, In this case the total operations needed to reach 1 is 1`. How is that?

Comment: i think there is an error in your example, how can you add 1 to 134, if it is divisible by one of the primes given? And the amount of operations to get to 1 from 135 is not 1, its 2

Comment: @KingsIndian He does not count divisions by primes from his list as "operations"; only adding/subtracting `1` count.

Comment: @ KingsIndian: The way is 1 is from 134 you add 1 so you reach 135. keep dividing 135 by 3 ... you will reach 5 and then divide by 5 so you reach 1.

Comment: @RupeshSaini What's the largest `N`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You can select an arbitrary limit. For practical purpose you can say limit of N is the largest 8 digit number

Comment: Why is there a `largest N`? Don't you run the algorithm for a specific `N`?

Comment: So you are saying you can make an operation N+1 even though it is divisible by the primes

Comment: @phant0m If there is a practical limit (e.g. you do not need an algorithm for a 100-digit bigint) a pseudo-polynomial solution can apply.

Comment: smells like a non deterministic syracuse problem variant

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is some mathematical solution for this problem (If you are looking for a mathematical solution, [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) is better for this question) - you could **reduce the problem to a [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)**.

Represent the problem as a graph `G=(V,E)` where `V = N` (all natural numbers) and `E = {(u,v) | you can get from u to v in a single step }`<sup>1</sup>.

Now, you need to run a classic search algorithm from your source (the input number) to your target (the number 1). Some of the choices to get an optimal solution are:

1. [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) - since the reduced graph is not weighted, BFS is guaranteed to be both complete (find a solution if one exists) and optimal (finds the shortest solution).
2. heuristic [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) - which is also complete and optimal<sup>2</sup>, and if you have a good heuristic function - should be faster then an uninformed BFS.

**Optimization note:**

The graph can be constructed "on the fly", no need to create it as pre-processing. To do so, you will need a `next:V->2^V` (from a node to a set of node) function, such that `next(v) = {u | (v,u) is in E}`

**P.S.** complexity comment: The BFS solution is pseudo-polynomial (linear in the input number worst case), since the "highest" vertex you will ever develop is `n+1`, so the solution is basically `O(n)` worst case - though I believe deeper analysis can restrict it to a better limit.

---

(1) If you are interested only in +1/-1 to be counted as ops, you can create the edges based on the target after finishing divisions.

(2) If an [admissible heuristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) is used.

Comment: Do have any thoughts about a heuristic function that might work here?

Comment: @phant0m: heuristic? sure, the number itself. *admissible heuristic*? This could be tricky I believe, I have no idea what could work - but maybe someone else can (that's why I mentioned this option, along with the uninformed alternative)